# Unable to browse website via DNS name in Azure VM

Tags: iis, azure

I'm trying to set up IIS on an Azure VM so that I can use make a small page to host images generated there.

I've set up IIS and from IIS Manager (while RDP'd to the VM) when I select the Default Website and select Browse *:80 (http) I can see the test page I created and placed at: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.htm

In the actions menu of IIS Manager below Browse Website is also the option to browse the site via the DNS Name.

When I click that option, I get an error in IE that "This page can't be displayed".

I checked the bindings and the only difference between the two is apparently that one has the DNS Name that I copied from the VM Overview page in Azure.

Any ideas on things to check to fix this?

Comment: `Any ideas on things to check to fix this?` - DNS?

Comment: Make sure to point it from domain provider too.. May be A record would be suffice pointing your ip to domain name at domain provider ie godaddy etc

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The DNS name is already set up by Azure by default.  It works fine for RDP... it's just not returning the default page I have set in IIS when I browse to it.  There is no domain provider involved this is just the Azure default DNS name I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Only add host name in IIS Management  ,cannot let you browser your website via DNS name.

1.If you want to browser your website just from a domain name, you can configure DNS name for your VM like this:

[image]

Then we can browser the web site via the DNS name I have configured.

[image]

2.If you want to browser your website from **your own domain name**,you can use Azure DNS. Also , you need to configure your domain name by your domain name provider.

More about Azure DNS, refer to [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-overview). You can also find how to delegate custom DNS with Azure DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The DNS name is already set up by Azure by default.  It works fine for RDP... it's just not returning the default page I have set in IIS when I browse to it.

Comment: Hi,@BleakMorn , Have you opened port 80 in your NSG ?

Comment: @BleakMorn , May I know that have you resolved your issue?